# Generate a column from different rows in sql

Tags: sql-server, mysql

I have a table that looks like this:

```
SKU          DateOut           DateIn          Status

123           1/2/2015          5/2/2016         1
123           10/2/2016         18/2/2016        1
123           20/2/2016                          0
```

Status 0 means no more rows for the given SKU.

I need to find out number of days online/stocked which would be generated by taking difference of `DateIN` of a row and `dateout` of the last row with in past 30 days from today.

Desired results in this case:

Let's say today is `7/3/2016` and I am looking for past 30 days i.e until date `7/2/2016`
so number of days online would be

```
(20/2/2016 - 18/2/2016) + (10/2/2016 - 7/2/2016)
2+3
```

-->5 days

I also need dates for which it was online.

```
 fromdate   todate
 18/2/2016   20/2/2016
 7/2/2016    10/2/2016
```

dateout means got offline(out of stock) this day and datein means stocked in back.

status 0 means never stocked again and 1 means there would be a next row.

how to do it in sql?

Also, number of days we are looking at should be in past 30 days only. I tried using case statement but none could really do all with it.

Edit:
This is what I had tried from my end but of course it does not give me the desired results and misses out on some cases like when data was stocked multiple times within past 30days.

```
Create TEMPORARY TABLE Temp.NumberOfDaysOnline AS 
SELECT so.sku as sku,
CASE
WHEN so.datein IS NULL AND so.status = 0 AND so.dateout IS NOT NULL AND so.dateout AND so.dateout < DATE_SUB(current_date(), 30) THEN 0
WHEN so.datein IS NULL AND so.status = 0 AND so.dateout IS NOT NULL AND so.dateout >= DATE_SUB(current_date(), 30) THEN DATEDIFF(so.dateout, DATE_SUB(current_date(), 30))
WHEN so.datein IS NOT NULL AND  so.status = 1 AND so.dateout < DATE_SUB(current_date(), 30) AND so.datein >= DATE_SUB(current_date(), 30)  THEN DATEDIFF(so.datein, DATE_SUB(current_date(), 30))
WHEN so.datein IS NOT NULL AND  so.status = 1 AND so.dateout >= DATE_SUB(current_date(), 30) AND so.datein >= DATE_SUB(current_date(), 30) THEN DATEDIFF(so.datein, so.dateout)
ELSE
0
END AS DaysOnline,
CASE
WHEN so.datein IS NULL AND so.status = 0 AND so.dateout < DATE_SUB(current_date(), 30) THEN NULL
WHEN so.datein IS NULL AND so.status = 0 AND so.dateout >= DATE_SUB(current_date(), 30) THEN DATE_SUB(current_date(), 30)
WHEN so.datein IS NOT NULL AND  so.status = 1 AND so.dateout < DATE_SUB(current_date(), 30) AND so.datein >= DATE_SUB(current_date(), 30)  THEN DATE_SUB(current_date(), 30)
WHEN so.datein IS NOT NULL AND  so.status = 1 AND so.dateout >= DATE_SUB(current_date(), 30) AND so.datein >= DATE_SUB(current_date(), 30) THEN so.dateout
ELSE
0
END AS FromDate,
CASE
WHEN so.datein IS NULL AND so.status = 0 AND so.dateout < DATE_SUB(current_date(), 30) THEN 0
WHEN so.datein IS NULL AND so.status = 0 AND so.dateout >= DATE_SUB(current_date(), 30) THEN so.dateout
WHEN so.datein IS NOT NULL AND  so.status = 1 AND so.dateout < DATE_SUB(current_date(), 30) AND so.datein >= DATE_SUB(current_date(), 30)  THEN so.datein
WHEN so.datein IS NOT NULL AND  so.status = 1 AND so.dateout >= DATE_SUB(current_date(), 30) AND so.datein >= DATE_SUB(current_date(), 30) THEN so.datein
ELSE
0
END AS ToDate,
FROM 
Erp.soldOut so
WHERE 
NOT(
so.status = 1
AND 
so.datein < DATE_SUB(current_date(), 30) 
AND
so.dateout < DATE_SUB(current_date(), 30) 
)
```

Edit: Another example:

```
SKU          DateOut           DateIn          Status

245           15/5/2016         19/5/2016       1
245           30/5/2016         3/6/2016        1
278           2/6/2016          5/6/2016        1
245           10/6/2016         18/6/2016        1
278           10/6/2016                           0
```

Now in this table, SKU 245 was brought into stock on 19th of May first.
It was in stock from `19/5/2016` to `30/5/2016`. and the cycle continues until 10th on which it got out of stock and never stocked in back (since the status is 0 and dateIN is null)

Now let' say we are looking at data only until 4/6/2016 considering that it it the 30th day back in time,

Number of days online  for past 30 days (until 4/6/2016 considering that it it the 30th day back in time) for SKU 245 would be

1. DATEDIFF(10/6/16 - 4/6/2016)
2. DATEDIFF(21/6/16 - 18/6/2016)

//TAKING `4/6/2016` and not `3/6/2016` since we are looking at data until 4/6/2016 and not before that so even if it was in stock on `3/6/2016` as well which is when it got into stock, it does not matter to us.

i.e

```
 DATEDIFF(10/6/16 - 4/6/2016) 
              +
    DATEDIFF(21/6/16 - 18/6/2016)
```

= `6 + 3`
= `9  days`. 
`SKU 245` was stocked In on `18/6/2016` and status `1` means it is in stock ever since. Never got out of stock since then and number of days online for this would be `30` (since it online for all the `30 days` we are looking at if it never got out of stock.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64690/discussion-on-question-by-simran-kaur-generate-a-column-from-different-rows-in-s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To address this problem, I did the following (I'm using PostgreSQL for this, but SQL Server has `CTE`s and `RECURSIVE CTE`s and window/analytic functions. I doubt if this can be done in MySQL - maybe using variables - not sure). PostgreSQL is as powerful as the big boys - MySQL is really a toy!

Created a table:

```
CREATE TABLE stock (sku int, datein date, dateout date, status int);
```

Populated it thus:

```
INSERT INTO stock VALUES (123, '2015-02-01', '2015-02-05', 1);
INSERT INTO stock VALUES (123, '2015-02-10', '2015-02-10', 1);
INSERT INTO stock VALUES (123, '2015-02-20', NULL,         0);
```

Then, I constructed the first part of my query. The actual dates to and from will obviously vary depending on the requirements - I assumed that (from the sample data), the OP wanted to look at the month of February. I constructed the following `RECURSIVE CTE` to construct a list of the days in February - PostgreSQL has the nifty [generate_series](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-srf.html) function, but that's proprietary and I wanted to make my query portable (to the greatest extent possible). This is the [best explanation](http://www.vertabelo.com/blog/technical-articles/sql-recursive-queries) of `RCTE`s I came across.

```
WITH RECURSIVE dates (test_date) AS
(
  SELECT '2015-02-01'::DATE
  UNION ALL
  SELECT test_date + 1 FROM dates
  WHERE test_date < '2015-02-28'
)
```

Now, I thought that the organisation of the raw data was poor, so I used `CTE`s to rearrange the data.

Get the outdates from the raw data:

```
out_dates AS
(
  SELECT dateout AS dout FROM stock
)
```

Get the indates from the raw data:

```
in_dates AS
(
  SELECT datein AS din FROM stock
)
```

Then I "transpose" the data - have to use two steps because one cannot use a Window function in a `WHERE` clause

```
transpose AS
(
  SELECT lag(dateout) over() AS datein, datein AS dateout FROM stock
  -- WHERE lag(datein) over() IS NOT NULL AND dateout IS NOT NULL <<-- can't use here.
  ORDER BY dateout, datein
)
```

And then

```
ranges AS
(
  SELECT * FROM transpose
  WHERE datein IS NOT NULL AND dateout IS NOT NULL
),
```

The result of this query is:

```
datein|dateout
2015-02-05|2015-02-10
2015-02-18|2015-02-20
```

Note that this corresponds to the in and out dates, but now the data is much simpler to handle because it's structure is more logical - it's chronologically coherent - thanks to the use of the `LAG` window function.

Now, we bring it all together with the next query:

```
x AS
(
  SELECT test_date, CASE WHEN has_match THEN 1 ELSE 0 END::int AS flag
  FROM 
  (
    SELECT test_date, 
    EXISTS
    (
      SELECT 1 
      FROM ranges 
      WHERE dates.test_date BETWEEN ranges.datein AND ranges.dateout
    ) AS has_match
  FROM dates  
  ) range_checks
)
SELECT * FROM x;
```

This gives a series of records for the month that are of this form:

```
test_date|flag
--------------
2015-02-01|0
2015-02-02|0
2015-02-03|0
2015-02-04|0
2015-02-05|1
2015-02-06|1
<other records snipped for brevity>
```

or use this as the final query

```
z AS 
(
  SELECT * FROM dates d
  LEFT JOIN ranges r
  ON (d.test_date BETWEEN r.datein AND r.dateout)
)
SELECT * FROM z;
```

for records of this form:

```
test_date|datein|dateout
2015-02-01||
2015-02-02||
2015-02-03||
2015-02-04||
2015-02-05|2015-02-05|2015-02-10
2015-02-06|2015-02-05|2015-02-10
<rest of the records snipped for brevity>
```