# Using results from one query as the parameters for another

Tags: sql-server, subquery

Is there a way to have a SQL query automatically update its' parameters based on the results of a previous query?

Here's the scenario I'm trying to achieve:

A report should automatically be run daily that runs the following queries (in order):

1. SELECT id of rows that match a certain criteria (we'll call this result set "X")
2. SELECT certain fields from rows that are titled "Cancelled-[X]"
3. UPDATE rows from [X] with information from "Cancelled-[X]"

Answer (score 2):

Consider using Common Table Expressions (`CTE`s).

I don't have your table structures nor your queries, but what I would envisage is something like this:

```
WITH cte1 AS
(
  Perform your 1.SELECT id of rows that match a certain criteria (we'll call this result set "X")`
),
cte2 AS
(
  Perform you 2.SELECT certain fields from rows that are titled "Cancelled-[X]"
)
UPDATE rows from [X] with information from "Cancelled-[X]";
```

There are some restrictions on `CTE`s. You can't perform `UPDATE`s from them for example. I'm not really a MS SQL Server person, but here are a couple of references which should help ([1](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/sql-server-cte-basics/), [2](https://dwaincsql.com/2014/03/23/common-table-expressions-in-sql/)).

For an example of them in action, see my post [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/145177/34007). It's a PostgreSQL solution, but the MS SQL Server syntax is virtually identical.

Answer (score 0):

Use local Temp Table in your procedure:

```
SELECT id INTO #X
FROM ABC WHERE MyCriteria = 'XYZ';

SELECT * FROM ABC 
WHERE Cancelled = 'Yes' and 
    id in (SELECT id FROM #X);

UPDATE ABC SET MyColumn = 'Updated'
WHERE Cancelled = 'Yes' and 
    id in (SELECT id FROM #X);
```